# Data field with a list of values in it

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm creating a form that has a `dropdownlist` for dept.

The place i work for has only a field with like 50 departments in the field itself. If i query that field and return it to a string on the CS file, **how can i break the different departments all up to binding to the ddl**?

Some departments have two names that have a space in between the words.

Comment: Are there any characters between the department names other than spaces?

Comment: no just "word word word word" and some of these departments consists of two words

Comment: How can you tell if a department is two words?  Using string.Split(" ") will split each word but there is no way to keep random words together.  You really need to fix the database by putting each department into a seperate row.

Comment: Don't you have any control over the data in the db?

Comment: @Vulcronos Or to put a comma(,) separator after each company name - no matter the spaces in between.

Comment: its a small hospital so i can tell what departments are two words

Comment: @user2835838 You can tell, but a computer can't (unless you tell it how)

Comment: @user2835838 If you can tell than save in in some dictionary and when splitting do your comparison to decide if the split would be after one or more spaces.

Comment: @YairNevet a comma seperator would work but still isn't good database desing.  And if you are changing the databases any way might as well make it the best change you can.  If he ever need to do any joins he won't be able to do it in SQL, he has to parse the list every time.  Poor performance and no good joining.

Comment: @Vulcronos Agree, but it's not seems that he can do it now.

Comment: i know the design isnt ideal but this is what i have to work with and i cant edit that table, but im going to try to ask my boss if i can create a new database and create tables for issues like this, cuz it somes a lil tedious or juts bad dartabase prcatise to have over 50 depts in one fields in a row of many fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything short of normalizing the table will result in something of a hack. I would consider creating a new table: Department. There you store each of the values in its own row. This will make data retrieval and, like @Vulcronos said, joining on another table much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The "right" answer is to modify the source to properly delimit the department names.

If you can't do that, and if the list is somewhat static you could use an "exception list" to indicate departments that should stay together:

```
string[] knownDepartments = new [] 
    {
        "Human Resources",
        "Community Services",
        etc.
    };
```

then just extract those from the source string before parsing:

```
foreach(string dept in knownDepartments)
    departments = departments.Replace(dept,"");
```

then parse the remaining departments (and tack on the known departments):

```
var departmentList = departments.Split(' ')
                                .Union(knownDepartments)
                                .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help and input, gonna set up new dept table and clean at least the miniscule mess of this DB